# Fluidsynth with Telnet and Python: No sound

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, telnet, telnetlib, fluidsynth

I've been working with Fluidsynth on a Raspberry Pi B running Raspian (not the absolute latest image because Fluidsynth wouldn't run on the latest version but from at least April 2014).

I start Fluidsynth by running `fluidsynth -a alsa -g 1 -s -o "shell.port=9800" /path/to/FluidR3_GM.sf2`

I am able to get the expected audio output using Fluidsynth's own shell with commands like `noteon 1 54 100` , and I can also get audio to play using a telnet server from a separate command line using:

`telnet localhost 9800` and then typing standard `noteon` commands into the subshell it spawns.

My ultimate goal, though, is to send these telnet commands from python.

I've tried the following code, which returns no errors:

```
>>> from telnet lib import Telnet
>>> fluidsynth = Telnet("localhost","9800")
>>> fluidsynth.write('noteon 1 25 127')
```

But this fails to produce any kind of sound.

At this point I've hit a wall, and I have no idea why the python statements won't work but the statements in the command shell will. Wouldn't they be doing the exact same thing? Am I missing some subtlety of the telnet protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Add a newline character to the end of the string you pass to `write`:

```
fluidsynth.write('noteon 1 25 127\n')
```

Comment: Awesome! Everything now works exactly as expected from Python.